# Ontotext GraphDb Multi-tenancy and Cloud Hosting Query

Tags: azure, graphdb

I had few questions enlisted regarding Ontotext GraphDb.

1. Is Ontotext supporting Multi-tenancy? I went through your documentation , it seems that graphdb server can have multiple repositories so are those repositories physically separated or logically separated?
2. Can the Ontotext GraphDb be hosted on another cloud platform like Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Each repository can serve multiple users and multiple repositories can be used at the same time. They are all both physically and logically separated.
2. GraphDB can be hosted on cloud platforms like Azure and AWS for example. For simplicity you can use the docker container and deploy it directly.